# Height for UIViewControllers don't go beyond 10,000

Tags: ios, xcode

I am making something that is longer than 10,000 height for a ScrollView and ViewController. I've made it 10,000 but when I go beyond 10,000 it gives an error, is there a way to go beyond 10,000?

I have used many apps that go beyond the number 10,000 but when I try to create something beyond 10,000 it would give me an error saying

> "Interface Builder does not support UIView sizes larger than 10,000 by
> 10,000."

This would help me a lot, if it would be possible, but I have seen a lot of apps that have a scrollView longer than 10,000. Need help!

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Would you not be better off making a table view for something like this? What is the content of the scroll view?

Answer (score 7):

After this annoying bug appeared in my project, I've been finally able to fix it following these steps:
(I had three views with a height of 24.142.523, one within another)

- First, I set a height constraint of 30 for the three views (starting from the more nested).
- Second I remove that constraints in the reverse order.

After this all *"Interface Builder does not support UIView sizes larger than 10,000 by 10,000."* errors disappeared.

Regards!

EDIT:

I've just noticed a weird thing. If I try to put a label with no text within a Stackview it sets a size of thousands, however if I set a text with a white space or a random string it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to make 'UIScrollView' so big? I hope it's because of settings the elements in the `UIScrollView`.

> Do the following things to solve:

1. Make `UIScrollView` as long as you have to! (Ignore error)
2. Set all you your elements in it.
3. Once all is done, resize the `UIScrollView` to fit into
   `UIStoryBoard` or under the specific area in which you need to display
   `UIScrollView`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a big subview that contained in scrollView, like a map, you'd better to do it programmatically, and better to split your 10000 size map into smaller pieces like 512 x 512, while user scrolling the map, load each piece lazily.

(And if you persist to do it in one view, you can do it as you like programmatically w/o that warning, though it's not recommended.)

---

But if you want to make the scrollview large enough to contain sth else, then you'r in wrong direction to solve the problem, you should modify scrollView's contentSize instead of frame:

```
[yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(10000.f, 10000.f)];
```

Comment: what is this in swift form?

Comment: @jasbath if u mean the 2nd choice, then `yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:10000.f, height:10000.f);`

Comment: @Kjuly `.f` does not work in Swift. You can just pass `10000` or `10_000` for better clarity.

Comment: I still haven't found a way to go beyond 10,000. This is confusing me!

Comment: @jasbath `yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:10000, height:10000);` doesn't work for ur case?

Comment: I uploaded an image to show you that it goes up to 10000. When I try to go beyond, when I run it, it still shows up as the same size. When I change the scrollView size or viewController size in Main.storyboard from the Size Inspector then it gives the error and dose not run :(

Comment: @jasbath how did u tell it's the same size while u'r scrolling down? have u added some subviews on the scrollview. Btw, what's the layout & frame of ur 3 scrollviews? is there any one cover the another?

Comment: i was able to tell it was the same because I put labels indicating where it started and ended. No I did not add subviews on the scrollview. I do have 3 scrollviews but if I can get beyond 10000 then there is no need of the other 2 subviews

Comment: I put more images to help everyone out. Let me know what other information you need!

Comment: @jasbath _"i was able to tell it was the same because I put labels indicating where it started and ended."_ might the way u put the labels is wrong, u need to layout the labels based on scrollview's contentSize as well, not it's frame. did u?

Comment: iI did layout the labels, by layout you mean by giving it constraints?

Comment: @jasbath u added constraints in IB or programmatically? i suggest u do it programmatically based on scrollview's content size for ur case.

Comment: yeah I did do it IB but it don't it will make a difference if I do it programmatically. But I will do it programmatically from now on. Do you know why this gives me an error ?  I've seen many apps that scroll from top to bottom and they have more than a scroll of 10000. I know this because it's extremely long.

Comment: @jasbath i suggest you take a time to read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html & https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html, i think it'll helps u much to understand how scrollview works.

Comment: Still at same problem, if you want me to do it all programmatically I can but it would take a really long time and there is a possibility that it might not even still work. I have a view controller and inside of it I have a scrollView. The man the view Controller goes up to is 10000. Is this the same for the scrollView?