# How to make UIScrollView larger than 10.000 px in iOS Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I have UIViewController that contain scroll view this scroll view contains forms this forms height more than 10,000px and it gives me error in Xcode

I found this Q) [Height for UIViewControllers don't go beyond 10,000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759029/height-for-uiviewcontrollers-dont-go-beyond-10-000)

but no answer

Comment: Have you tried doing it programmatically?

Comment: It will be difficult to make all this forms programmatically
I want to design the forms on IB